# v # invalid expression\nsre_constants.error: bad character range , Ansible

Tags: python, regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using Ansible to write a content to a file which looks like :

```
[localhost]
localhost

[es-master]

[es-data]

[es-client]
```

The play is :

```
 - name: Debug the variable name
        debug:
              msg={{ ec2_details | type_debug }}

      - name: Add Instances to local inventory file
        local_action:
          lineinfile path="~/ansible-environments/hosts"
            regexp="^[es-master]"
            insertafter="^#?[es-master]"
            line="{{ item.private_ip }}"
            state="present"
        with_items: "{{ ec2_details.instances }}"
```

I can see that the result is a dictionary and the value is present but i am not able to pick the particular keys and write it file. Now i am not sure if i am correctly using the reg-ex , but here is what i see

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_b91Bg5/ansible_module_lineinfile.py", line 461, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_b91Bg5/ansible_module_lineinfile.py", line 453, in main
    ins_aft, ins_bef, create, backup, backrefs)
  File "/tmp/ansible_b91Bg5/ansible_module_lineinfile.py", line 251, in present
    bre_m = re.compile(to_bytes(regexp, errors='surrogate_or_strict'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range

failed: [localhost -> localhost] (item={u'kernel': None, u'root_device_type': u'ebs', u'private_dns_name': u'ip-172-16-9-68.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal', u'public_ip': None, u'private_ip': u'172.16.9.68', u'id': u'i-0d4310cf82c52fd0b', u'ebs_optimized': False, u'state': u'running', u'virtualization_type': u'hvm', u'architecture': u'x86_64', u'ramdisk': None, u'block_device_mapping': {u'/dev/sda1': {u'status': u'attached', u'delete_on_termination': True, u'volume_id': u'vol-04be65eead21e611f'}}, u'key_name': u'ansible-managed', u'image_id': u'ami-325d2e4e', u'tenancy': u'default', u'groups': {u'sg-1e3c9d79': u'elasticsearch-mayassar-production', u'sg-86018ce2': u'mayassar-es-external'}, u'public_dns_name': u'', u'state_code': 16, u'tags': {u'Name': u'Kill-master-es'}, u'placement': u'ap-southeast-1b', u'ami_launch_index': u'0', u'dns_name': u'', u'region': u'ap-southeast-1', u'launch_time': u'2018-01-17T04:49:28.000Z', u'instance_type': u'm4.4xlarge', u'root_device_name': u'/dev/sda1', u'hypervisor': u'xen'}) => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "item": {
        "ami_launch_index": "0", 
        "architecture": "x86_64", 
        "block_device_mapping": {
            "/dev/sda1": {
                "delete_on_termination": true, 
                "status": "attached", 
                "volume_id": "vol-04be65eead21e611f"
            }
        }, 
        "dns_name": "", 
        "ebs_optimized": false, 
        "groups": {
            "sg-1e3c9d79": "elasticsearch-mayassar-production", 
            "sg-86018ce2": "mayassar-es-external"
        }, 
        "hypervisor": "xen", 
        "id": "i-0d4310cf82c52fd0b", 
        "image_id": "ami-325d2e4e", 
        "instance_type": "m4.4xlarge", 
        "kernel": null, 
        "key_name": "ansible-managed", 
        "launch_time": "2018-01-17T04:49:28.000Z", 
        "placement": "ap-southeast-1b", 
        "private_dns_name": "ip-172-16-9-68.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal", 
        "private_ip": "172.16.9.68", 
        "public_dns_name": "", 
        "public_ip": null, 
        "ramdisk": null, 
        "region": "ap-southeast-1", 
        "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
        "root_device_type": "ebs", 
        "state": "running", 
        "state_code": 16, 
        "tags": {
            "Name": "Kill-master-es"
        }, 
        "tenancy": "default", 
        "virtualization_type": "hvm"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_b91Bg5/ansible_module_lineinfile.py\", line 461, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_b91Bg5/ansible_module_lineinfile.py\", line 453, in main\n    ins_aft, ins_bef, create, backup, backrefs)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_b91Bg5/ansible_module_lineinfile.py\", line 251, in present\n    bre_m = re.compile(to_bytes(regexp, errors='surrogate_or_strict'))\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py\", line 194, in compile\n    return _compile(pattern, flags)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py\", line 251, in _compile\n    raise error, v # invalid expression\nsre_constants.error: bad character range\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 0
}
```

Please Help me debug this part of the code , any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**7.2.1. Regular Expression Syntax**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)
>
> [ ] Some characters, like '`|`' or '`(`', are special. Special characters either stand for classes of ordinary characters, or affect how the regular expressions around them are interpreted. [ ]
>
> The special characters are: [ ]
>
> `[]` Used to indicate a set of characters.

So you cannot use `^[es-master]` to match `[es-master]` because `[` and `]` **are special characters**.

You need to escape them.

Comment: thank you , i though have a small problem i used now 
`  regexp="^\[esmaster\]"
        insertafter="^#?\[esmaster\]" ` , which actually doesn't insert the ip after the esmaster, but overwrites on top of it

Comment: Can you help me with that ?

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite "the esmaster" you shouldn't use `regexp` argument. Please do minimal research (like reading the docs) before asking questions on SO.